# About the number of faces of the conification of a polytope

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, discrete-geometry, convex-polytopes, polyhedra, polytopes

Let $P\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ be a polytope of dimension $(n-1)$ such that the origin $\vec{0}\not\in\text{Aff}(P)$, where $\text{Aff}(P)$ denotes the affine hull of $P$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$. Now, we consider the conification of $P$,
$$C:=\mathbb{R}_{\geq0}\cdot P:=\Big\{\lambda\cdot x:\;\lambda\geq0,\; x\in P\Big\}.$$

Then we claim (or we conjecture) that for each $\ell\in[0,1,\ldots,n-1]$ :

### The number of $(\ell+1)$-faces of the cone C is equal (or at least less) than the number of $\ell$-faces of the polytope P.

Where a $k$-face of a polyhedron is a face of dimension $k$ in such polyhedron.

**Although it seems obvious in a 3-dimensional space, we are interested in finding some book (or paper) of reference or some idea of its proof in any dimension.**

¡Thanks for any comment!:)